# How to work with an array from ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, ajax

I am getting an array with id´s from my html table(based on database)(only if they are selected)
Now I want to send this array (ajax) to my php script to delete entries with those id´s but this does not work.

```
    var $rows = [];
    $(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
        // start plugin
        $('#myTable').TableSelection({
                sort : false, // sort or not (true | false)
                status : 'multiple', // single or multiple selection (default is 'single')
            }, function(obj){ // callback function return selected rows array
                $rows = obj.rows;
                console.log($rows);
        });

    });

            // Get HTML Object from row in array
        function showSelectedRow(array){
        $.each(array, function(i, row){
            $('#info').append('<li>'
                + $('#myTable').RowValue(row).find('td').eq(0).html() // HTML Object
                + '</li>');
              });
        var deleteIds = array.map(function(currentValue) {
          return $('#myTable').RowValue(currentValue).find('td').eq(0).html();
        });

       $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST", 
       url: "includes/datenloeschen.php", 
       data: { kvcArray : deleteIds}, 
       success: function() { 
        alert("Success"); 
        } 
}); 
        console.log(deleteIds[0])
    }
```

```php
<?php
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    $artid = ['kvcArray'];
    /* $artid = 1; */

    $sql = "DELETE FROM artikel WHERE id= $artid;";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    header("Location: ../index.php?daten=success");
```

success alert pops up.
If I set $artid it works so something with kvcArray( ajax) should be the problem.
In deleteIds are entries.

Comment: `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kvcArray` is **array** of values.

```
$artid = ['kvcArray'];  // here you assign array with one element `'kvcArray'` to `$artid` variable.
```

It should be at least:

```
$artid = $_POST['kvcArray']; // as your ajax-method is POST.
```

Next - you **can't** just pass array to a query text. In your case deleting should be done with query like:

```
DELETE FROM artikel WHERE id IN (1,2,3)  // where 1,2,3 are values from your `$artid`
```

So, skipping checks that array not empty and has valid numbers (I suppose `id` is number), script can be:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM artikel WHERE id IN (" . implode(', ', $artid)  . ")";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location: ../index.php?daten=success");
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much <3